# Hibernate Mapping many to one table with annotations

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, or-mapper

How would I create a HQL query to select the patients mutiple email address when provided with the fields patient firstname and lastname. tables and classed provided below.

```
CREATE TABLE Patient (
Patient_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
First_Name VARCHAR(55)  NOT NULL,
Middle_Name VARCHAR(55),
Last_Name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
Is_Male TINYINT NOT NULL,
Medical_Information VARCHAR(5000),
Date_Of_Birth DATE,
Row_Create DATETIME NOT NULL,
Row_LastUpdate DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (  Patient_id),
INDEX name(First_Name, Last_Name)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE Address (
PatientAddress_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Patient_Id INT NOT NULL,
House_Name VARCHAR(100),
House_Number VARCHAR(20),
Street VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
Postcode VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
County VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Row_Create DATETIME NOT NULL,
Row_LastUpdate DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (  PatientAddress_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_Id)
REFERENCES Patient(Patient_Id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
INDEX HouseNum_Street(House_Number, Street),
INDEX PatientID_postcode(Patient_Id, Postcode)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Here I create a patient class and and set all the fields and annotate the relationship
**Patient Class**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@NamedQueries(
        value = {
               @NamedQuery(
                    name = "findPatientByFirstName",
                        query = "from Patient p where p.firstName = :name"
                ),
                @NamedQuery(
                        name = "findPatientByLastName",
                        query = "from Patient p where p.lastName = :name"
                ),
                @NamedQuery(
                    name = "findPatientByDOB",
                        query = "from Patient p where  p.dob = :dob"
                    ),
                @NamedQuery(
                        name = "findPatientByFullName",
                        query = "from Patient p where p.firstName = :firstName AND p.lastName = :lastName"
            )



    }
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "Patient_id")
private Integer id;

@Column( name="Date_Of_Birth")
private LocalDate dob;

@Column( name="First_Name")
private String firstName;

@Column( name="Middle_Name")
private String middleName;

@Column( name="Last_Name")
private String lastName;

@Column( name="Medical_Information")
private String medicalInformation;

@Column( name="Is_Male")
private boolean isMale;

@Column (name = "Row_Create")
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

@Column (name = "Row_LastUpdate")
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;

public Patient() {
}

public Patient(LocalDate dob, String firstName, String lastName, String medicalInformation, boolean isMale) {
    this.dob = dob;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.medicalInformation = medicalInformation;
    this.isMale = isMale;
}
//Setters and getters
```

**Patient Email Class**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;


@NamedQueries(
    value = {
         @NamedQuery(
                    name = "findEmailByPatientsName",
                    query = "SELECT pE.patient from PatientEmailAddress pE 
join pE.emailAddress e where pE.patient = :patient"
                   // select cus.mail from Customer cus join cus.mainOrder man WHERE man.id = 1
            )
    }
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "patientEmailAddress")
public class PatientEmailAddress {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PatientEmailAddress_Id", unique = true)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "Email_Address", unique = true)
private String emailAddress;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "Patient_id")
private Patient patient;

@Column (name = "Row_Create")
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

@Column (name = "Row_LastUpdate")
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;


public PatientEmailAddress() {
}

public PatientEmailAddress(String emailAddress, Patient patient) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.patient = patient;
}
//setters and getters
```

I'm struggling to find the soloution.

Comment: There is a lot of code here. Are you able to edit it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mc)

Comment: Edit: Removed setters and getters so its more compact

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in the PatientEmailAddress instances related to one Patient you could query for those entities using something like:

```
select t from PatientEmailAddress t 
    join t.patient p
where p.firstName = :firstName and p.lastname = :lastname
```

Note that this will return instances of PatientEmailAddress and not of Patient.